# Java interface generics, return type depending on argument generic

Tags: java, generics

I have several objects all implementing a concrete interface *Op* that need to be mapped to
arbitrary types. I'm trying to solve the problem with a double-dispatch approach:

```java
interface Mapper<R> {
    R process(Op1 op1);
    R process(Op2 op2);
}

interface Op<T>{
    <R> R process(Mapper<R> mapper);
}

class Op1 implements Op<String> {
    @Override
    public <R> R process(Mapper<R> mapper) {
        return mapper.process(this);
    }
}

class Op2 implements Op<String> {
    @Override
    public <R> R process(Mapper<R> mapper) {
        return mapper.process(this);
    }
}
```

I create a mapper with methods for the specified *Ops*, mapping to *String*:

```java
Mapper<String> mapper = new Mapper<String>() {
    @Override
    public String process(Op1 op1) {
        return "1";
    }

    @Override
    public String process(Op2 op2) {
        return "2";
    }
};
```

### Problem

When I try to map an *Op* to *String*:

```java
Op op = new Op1();

String i = op.process(mapper);
```

The return type of process is *Object* and not *String*. If I change the *Op* interface, removing the generic, the code works like intended:

```java
interface Op{
    <R> R process(Mapper<R> mapper);
}
```

Why is the compiler not accepting the generics definition in *Op* interface?

Comment: You don't make use of the generics on `Op`.  What were you hoping to gain from having them there?

Comment: You say "the compiler [is] not accepting the generics definition" but haven't included an error message. It's hard to know exactly what issue you're having without the exact error message you're seeing.

Comment: @Makoto you're right, i don't use it in the example, but even if using the generic `T` on `Op` methods, the issue with the `op.process` type is the same. If i remove the `T`, `op.process` returns the correct type.

Comment: As an aside, this is the visitor pattern, and it looks like your implementation is mostly correct aside from the unused `T` type parameter.

Comment: @LaurenceGonsalves yes, the error is of incompatible types assignment, `op.process` returns Object, when i wanted it to return String.

Comment: You're calling a generic method on a raw type, which causes lots of screwiness. Enable unchecked conversion warnings (`-Xlint:unchecked` in `javac`) and fix your code so there are no more warnings. rgettman's answer shows the issue with the posted code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using a raw type when you assign your `Op1` to a variable of the type `Op`.  `Op` is generic, but you aren't supplying the generic type parameter, so type erasure occurs and the return type is `Object`, not `String`.  You did create an `Op1`, which is a `Op<String>`, but that information is lost when assigned to a raw `Op`.

It works when the generic type parameter is declared on the method instead of the interface, because type inference takes over and `R` is inferred to be `String`.

To get this to work when making the interface itself generic, only the generic type parameter needs to be supplied on the `Op` variable.  After all, an `Op1` is an `Op<String>`.

```
Op<String> op = new Op1();
```

Comment: This solution does work, but i had to know that `Op1` is an `Op<String>`. If I do `Op<?> op = new Op1();` it works as i intended. But why do i have to do that, and not just `Op op = new Op1();`

Comment: All generics in a class/interface undergo type erasure when the type is used as a raw type, even unrelated type parameters.  As it turns out, `Op<?>` will work too, because the method called is itself generic, rendering any generics defined on the interface useless.  It looks to be a better solution to remove the generic type parameter on the definition of the `Op` interface.

Comment: The issue i'm having is in the return type of `op.process(mapper);` that should depend on the `mapper` and not on `Op`. But if i do use `Op<?> op = new Op1();` it works as intended, my question is mainly why that happens?